# System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in EntityFramework.Relational.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-core

I am Developing an application using asp.net core while pushing data to local database using entity framework 7 (i.e. while calling Database`Database.EnsureCreated()` method) I am getting the following exeception:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in EntityFramework.Relational.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: **Please** don't use `asp.net` or `core` tags when referring to ASP.NET Core. **Neither** of the two tags is related to ASP.NET Core. use `asp.net-core` instead!!

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework.SqlServer: "7.0.0-beta8" Pull's all dependent reference which includes System.Data.SqlClient which made me believe all references are in place moreover there was no compile time warning. however at runtime it couldn't find reference to System.Data.SqlClient.

Adding reference to System.Data.Sqlclient worked for me.

Please go through attached image [Reference][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdodC.jpg